# C# Open Source Projects with good architecture

Tags: c#, architecture, open-source

I'm curious what are some good open source projects written in c# to learn about project architecture?

Comment: What type of project? (Winforms, Silverlight, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-very-high-code-quality-to-learn-from

Comment: The older question was (sadly, and imho unjustified) deleted. There is an [archived version here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090430100115/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-extremely-high-code-quality-to-learn-from) with broken layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

[Mef](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to study Autofac available at http://code.google.com/p/autofac/.

It's a very very good **Inversion Of Control** container (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). You could learn a lot by studying the source and doing this you'll be able to use it in your own projects.

You should ever consider using an IoC for decouple software components.

Regards,
Giacomo